# App engine - Data visible only for user who posted it

Tags: java, google-app-engine, orm, gmail, objectify

I'm creating a `Google App Engine` application in which each `user` connected through `gmail` can post some `data`. I want that each `user` connected to my app to see only his `posted data`.

How do I model this with `Java` & `Objectify`? Do I need to hava a separate `entity` user? or are there a more efficient way to achieve this with the `Gmail service`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution that has came to my mind, is to add each `connected user` that have posted data to `user` entity in the datastore. This way I can add a reference (foreign key), in `data` entity to the user who have posted it, in order to get `data` of a specific `user`.